# JQuery hide and show div id does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

JQuery hide and show does not work called from ajax. But the same code works on document.ready function.

First function test1 will be called via form on click.

Any reason to this?

```js
function test1(id){  
   $("#id").addClass('loading');

   jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'test',
    data: {
        'id': id,
    },
    success: function (res) {
        $("#id").removeClass('loading');

        if(res.status == 200){
            test2(100); // hide and show does not work
        }
        else{

        }
    }

   });
}
```

```js
function test2(n=0){
    $("#div1").hide();
    $("#div2").show();

}

$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#div2").hide();
   test2(0);  //works perfectly
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that res.status is 200?

Comment: @PalSingh yes, status returned is 200

Comment: What you see if write `console.log(res)` in success callback?

Comment: @Mamun result of  `res.status` is 200

Comment: please provide your `html` and how you register the event handlers

Comment: Check whether `complete` call back function works instead of `success` call back function

Comment: Try writing the `test2()` before `test1()`?

Comment: You can hide your div using css. and .toggle() for the modal so that you wont have to use the .hide() and .show() . Example if successfully received a response you will only have to call test2() without passing argument. And I don't understand where is the argument for.

Comment: since you are calling `test2` during `document.ready`, we wouldn't expect a later calling of `test2` to have any effect.  have you left out some implementation details that reset the state of #div1 and #div2?

Comment: @MikeK test2 function will be called on `document.ready` as well as from `test1 ` on click.

Comment: Why does function test2 has parameter n=0? Is the issue because of this? From your document.ready function you are calling like test2(0) and from ajax you are calling like test2(100).

Answer (score 0):

**res.status** should be undefined. You can verify that by writing to the console. Furthermore, you can write to the console in the else statement.

```
    if(res.status == 200){
        test2(100); // hide and show does not work
    }
    else{
       console.log('hit else statement');
    }
```

You should use the [jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) for HTTP stats code, but I am almost certain checking for status 200 is not necessary inside of the .success() callback. Rather, I think you should use the .error() callback if your using jQuery 2, and the .fail() callback if you're using jQuery 3 to check for errors.

Just replace the type and url and it should work for you. Also, I think your selectors in test1() are wrong.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .loading {background-color:black;}
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="loading">Loading</div>
    <div id="div1">div 1</div>
    <div id="div2">div 2</div>

    <input type="button" value="call test1" onclick="test1('loading');" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test1(id)
        {
            $("#" + id).addClass('loading');

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
                data: {
                    'id': id,
                },
                success: function (res, textStatus, xhr)
                {
                    $("#" + id).removeClass('loading');
                    console.log(xhr.status);
                    //console.log(res.status);

                    if (xhr.status == 200)
                    {
                        test2(100); // hide and show does not work
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }

            });;
        }

        function test2(n = 0)
        {
            $("#div1").hide();
            $("#div2").show();
        }

        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $("#div2").hide();
            test2(0);  //works perfectly
          
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```